# systemd script not starting my service on reboot

Tags: systemd

I have below systemd script which is supposed to restart my exhibitor but after server reboot, it is not starting at all. I have tried rebooting my server manually (sudo reboot) many times and my exhibitor service doesn't run single time. I am not sure what's wrong. I need to manually restart my systemd to make it work after system reboot. How to debug what's wrong?

```
[Unit]
Description= start zookeeper cluster

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=3
LimitNOFILE=100000
LimitCORE=infinity
StartLimitInterval=0
WorkingDirectory=/opt/exhibitor/exhibitor-1.6.0/lib
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "exec java -jar ./exhibitor-1.6.0.jar -c file --fsconfigdir /opt/exhibitor/conf --hostname some.host.com > exhibitor.out"
User=procapp

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Status output:

```
david@some.host.com:~$ sudo systemctl status exhibitor_server.service
● exhibitor_server.service - start zookeeper cluster
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/exhibitor_server.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to start automatically on system reboot? Have you enabled it with `sudo systemctl enable exhibitor_server.service`?

Comment: `vendor preset` is enabled already so why do I need to enable my service?

Answer (score 3):

Despite having created a systemd service, for it to start on boot you need to have enabled it using `systemctl`. To do so:

`sudo systemctl enable exhibitor_server.service`